# Load view passing variable to the controller's function - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

I'm using CodeIgniter and want to load a view such as:

```
$this->load->view('image/delete/' . $_POST['id'], $data);
```

The $_POST['id'] is a required parameter of my 'delete' function inside my 'image' controller.  I would have thought this would work fine, but I'm getting a CI error stating:

"Unable to load the requested file: image/delete/113.php"

I don't understand why CI is adding ".php" to the end of this, no wonder it can't find this file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Loading a view is not the same as loading a URL. A view is a file stored locally on your hard drive(well the servers), and you pass data to it via $data. You are attempting to pass data via URL and PHP is looking for an actual file of image/delete/113.php (automatically appends .php to views/controllers/models etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ivan's answer, what you're trying to do is violating the MVC principle: separation of concern.

Views should just display data, they should not ever gain functionality like deleting resources.

Instead of loading a view, you'd need to use the `redirect()` function in the [URL helper class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to redirect the browser the url `"image/delete/".$image_id`

Then, as Ivan suggested, you will need an `Image` controller with a `delete($id)` function. This function will delete your image and afterwards load a view to indicate the resource has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks, that helps - haha, I thought I might be 'violating the MVC principle', that doesn't surprise me.  I know it's there for my benefit, just gotta get used to it!

Answer (score 1):

> The .php file extension does not need to be specified unless you use
>   something other than .php.

Code in "image" controller:

```
public function delete($parameter=false)
{

some_delete_function($parameter);

//and load view

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the view to load the URL /image/delete/113. But it is trying to load the view ~application/views/images/delete/113 from your hard drive.

I'd recommend just deleting the image from your code, maybe create a library if it's complex or a helper if it is not, and call it from the controller there.

Comment: Is it not possible to load a view like: ('controller/function/parameter')?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'm not certain why you would want to. If you want to delete an image, just do "unlink(filename)"